# Meteor push to heroku with buildpack but rejected by unrecognized error

Tags: heroku, meteor

I follow the steps of this meteor buildpack (https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor) and tried to push to heroku. But it failed with unrecognized error. Did anyone see this problem before?

```
$ git push heroku master


-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Fetching custom buildpack... done
-----> meteor app detected
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  5239    0  5239    0     0  17760      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 43658
Fetching meteor deb package
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.0M  100 12.0M    0     0  3048k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 3187k
Unpacking meteor
Building meteor bundle
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types  -> (none)
       Default types for meteor -> web
-----> Compiled slug size is 11.8MB
-----> Launching...
 !     Heroku push rejected due to an unrecognized error.
 !     We've been notified, see http://support.heroku.com if the problem persists.


To git@xxxxxxxxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it now. Here is the similar problem to mine.
https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor/issues/1

It works fine after installing mongo on heroku app.

$ heroku addons:add mongohq:free
Adding mongohq:free on test-heroku-meteor... done, v3 (free)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku free version of mongohq used this command before

```
heroku addons:add mongohq:free
```

However, Jordan Sissel has kindly updated the buildpack using the new heroku nomenclature.

```
heroku addons:add mongohq:sandbox
```

https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor/pull/5